# how to make sure two properties should not be the same in a schema mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mern

I am creating a inventory management system and I have to import data from an sql database.

So the id fields are numbers that are autoincremented. Client wants the same behavior for new ids as well. for that I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sequence this plugin.

This is what my product schema looks like

```
const { connection } = require("../../config/database");
const AutoIncrementFactory = require("mongoose-sequence");
const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection);

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    oldBarcode: { type: Number, required: false, unique: true },
    newBarcode: { type: Number, required: false, unique: true },
    //other irrelevant fields
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
ProductsSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {
 inc_field: "newBarcode",
 start_seq: 1000,
});

const Product = connection.model("products", ProductsSchema, "products");

module.exports = Product
```

As you can see here the strategy I am using is I will get the list of products from client first and start the timer from the max value in old barcode

ex if client has 900 products the max value for id possible on sql will be 900 so I will start at 1000 in that way when I import data newBarcode will never be equal to oldBarcode

but is there a way to put that condition on schema itself